# How to align elements in a section in gsp while using grails

Tags: css, grails, alignment, gsp

I am trying to display an image on the right of an already existing table in gsp.

Below is my code.

```
<body>
    <section>
            <div id=“image”></div>
            <section>
            <q:search/>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                </table>
            </div>
            </section>
      </section>
</body>
```

Right now the image div is on top of the table. I need it to be to the right of the table always. How can I do that?.

Finally it works, I did it like this. Is there a better way?.

```
<div style="clear:both; width:100%">

     <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;float:left;width:50%;">

     </div>

     <div style="float:left;max-width:30%;max-height:20%;margin-bottom:30px" >

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS, as it is impossible to know what your classes do without it.

Comment: can you share the css for that

Comment: I don't follow...I don't have access to your CSS.

Comment: I dont have any css. its just using bootstrap css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this. Is there a better way?.

```
<div style="clear:both; width:100%">

     <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;float:left;width:50%;">

     </div>

     <div style="float:left;max-width:30%;max-height:20%;margin-bottom:30px" >

     </div>
</div>
```